# jQuery hide only if visible, show only if hidden

Tags: jquery

When using jQuery, is it possible to hide a `div` only if it is not hidden, and show it only if it is not shown, instead of adding the same classes to it again?

Can something like an if be used there?

**Eg:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".trigger").click(function() {
    // Hide it but only if not hidden - hide
    // Later in the script - Show it but only If it's not visible. 
 });
});

<div class="user">Example Div</div> 
<div class="trigger">Load</div>
```

I've stripped things down for this question. The real thing is a lot different.

**Edit**

Toggle is not what I'm trying to do. Toggle will change a class. I'm compulsorily trying to hide it, but only if it's not hidden. That is: add the hidden class only if it's current class is not hidden.

```
If class != 'hidden' then add the Hidden class
```

Comment: `.toggle()` would do.

Comment: `.toggle()` is what you are looking for

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Toggle is not what I'm trying to do. See my edit.

Comment: `$("trigger").is(":visible")` worked for me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(".user").click(function () {
    // Hide it but only if not hidden - hide
    $('.trigger:visible').hide();

    // Later in the script - Show it but only If it's not visible.  
    $('.trigger:hidden').show();
});
```

For some more context, elements are deemed ":hidden" if:

- They have a CSS display value of none.
- They are form elements with type="hidden".
- Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
- Or an ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

Additionally, "elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered to be visible."

Source: https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector

Comment: Thanks for understanding what I was asking.

Comment: I haven't actually tested this so I may be wrong but wouldn't this code hide the element and then try to show it again because it had been hidden?

Answer (score 2):

Use an instance of `this` and `toggle`

```
$(".user").click(function() {
    // Only if not hidden - hide
    // Later in the script - Only If not visible show. 
    $(this).next(".trigger").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.toggleClass()` to toggle visibility, either with `visibility` or `display`. It requires you to set a default visibility state and have the class that is used in `.toggleClass()` have the opposite state.

```
.user {
    display: block;
}

.visibility {
    display: none;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".user").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('visibility');

    });
});

<div class="user">Example Div</div> 
<div class="trigger">Load</div>
```

**Edit:** As others have mentioned, using `.toggle()` will do just this, it will change the `display` property.

Comment: Isn't this just massive overkill when you can simply `toggle()` or check `is(":visible")`?

Comment: The problem with this is that once .user is hidden, it won't be displayed again (since a div with display : none can't be clicked). Obviously, this is more an issue of thinking through the goal than an issue with the answer, but one the OP should think about.

Comment: Great point @jameslafferty! OP, using `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible` would allow the element to still be clicked but it would still take up space in the DOM.

Comment: I landed here by searching for a solution to show if hidden or hide if shown without having to write decision flow. By clicking on a button you 1) see the content, clicking again will 2) hide it. One-line solution. Thank you very much.